# Playing with Intervals in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have my object called player

```
var player = new Object();
 player = {
 x: (window.innerWidth / 2),
 y: (window.innerHeight / 2),
 width: 30,
 height: 30,
 color: 'red'
};
```

And some variable to check mouse down clicks

```
var mouseDown = 0;
```

And I have functions that is firing every 40ms...

```
function drawPlayer() {
var toPlayerX;
var toPlayerY;
var toPlayerLength;
toPlayerX = player.x - mouseX;
toPlayerY = player.y - mouseY;
toPlayerLength = Math.sqrt(toPlayerX * toPlayerX + toPlayerY * toPlayerY);
toPlayerX = toPlayerX / toPlayerLength;
toPlayerY = toPlayerY / toPlayerLength;
toPlayerLength = toPlayerLength - (toPlayerLength%1);

// this function get reduced distance between mouse and player canvas rect by 1px per click
function movePlayer() {
    player.x -= toPlayerX;
    player.y -= toPlayerY;
}
// on MOUSE DAWN EVENT
document.body.onmousedown = function() {
    // on every mouse down click ++ mousedawn
    ++mouseDown;
    // here we fire interval to make player alive and 
    // follow to mouse dawn click by ~25 pixels per secord
    if (mouseDown==1) {
        setInterval(movePlayer,40);
    }
    if (mouseDown>1) {
        clearInterval(movePlayer());
        mouseDown = 0;
    }
};
}
```

The root of the problem is in this part

```
    if (mouseDown>1) {
        clearInterval(movePlayer());
        mouseDown = 0;
    }
```

I thought it will be clear movePlayer interval if mouseDown will have number of two, but instead the setInterval(movePlayer) just multiplie all the time while I click mouse, and making mouseDown = 0 works pretty well when it's go number of 2.
At the beginning I just wanna make code so when user clicks in some area the canvas player would follow straightly on area where the mouse was clicked and then stopped and while for example player is going somewhere already and the mouse was click again to change canvas first destination to area where the mouse was clicked last.

Comment: `movePlayer` returns nothing, or in other words it returns `undefined`, so really you're doing `clearInterval(undefined)`. The `setInterval` method takes an ID referencing an interval as it's argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `setInterval` command to a variable, and that is what you use to clear it.

So your code would look something like this:

```
// this function get reduced distance between mouse and player canvas rect by 1px per click
function movePlayer() {
    player.x -= toPlayerX;
    player.y -= toPlayerY;
}

var intervalID;  // Declare the variable that is storing the interval.

// on MOUSE DAWN EVENT
document.body.onmousedown = function() {
    // on every mouse down click ++ mousedawn
    ++mouseDown;
    context.save();
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.restore();
    // here we fire interval to make player alive and follow to mouse dawn click by ~15 pixels per secord
    if (mouseDown==1) {
        intervalID = setInterval(movePlayer,40);
    }
    if (mouseDown>1) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        mouseDown = 0;
    }
};
document.body.onmouseup = function() {
    //--mouseDown;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`clearInterval` takes an `intervalID` returned from `setInterval`.

```
var timeoutId = 0;
if (mouseDown==1) {
    timeoutId = setInterval(movePlayer,40);
}
if (mouseDown>1) {
    clearInterval(timeoutId);
    mouseDown = 0;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval